# How may I use the ifstream to read an info from a FIFO?

Tags: c++, linux, fstream, fifo

I need to read an info (strings) from a FIFO in a cycle while another app will write into it. How may I use the ifstream to do this?

I have tried a plain algorithm like this:

```
ifstream fifo("/path/to/file");

while(true)
{
  // Check, if we need to break the cycle etc...
  if(!fifo.eof())
  {
    string s;
    fifo >> s;
    // Do something...
  }
}
```

but it reads the first line only. I have tried to add a call of the `seekg(0)`, but this didn't get anything. I have tried to use the `getline` instead of the `>>` operator -- with the same result.

Comment: can you edit your question It is not so much clear to me.

Comment: @Mohammad Tayyab, how may I enhance my question?

Comment: What do you want to do ? Just read whole file and then ?

Comment: Read an info line by line, when it appended to the FIFO at the other side.

Comment: @SergeRoussak - how do you know the other side finished to append the information?

Comment: @user31264, this app must exit when it will get a signal, not when an information is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the eof flag is set, it stays until you clear it. The following might work:

```
string s;
while (true) {
    fifo >> s;
    if (fifo.eof()) {
        sleep(1); // wait for another app to write something
        fifo.clear();
    }
    else {
        // do what you want with the string s
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ifstream fifo;
fifo.open("/path/to/file");

char output[100];

if (fifo.is_open()) {

   while (!fifo.eof()) {

      fifo >> output;
      //do whatever you want with the output

   }

}
else cout << "Cant open the file"<<endl;
```